# Javascript effects on mouse enter and mouse leave

Tags: javascript, function, mouseleave, mouseenter

I am very new to effects of javascript etc...but I was able to make some stuff up. I made a fading effect, but I prefer doing it without fading. How can I modify that so I dont use fading and just give effect on mouse enter and mouse leave without fading.

This is my current code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".teamImage").fadeTo(20, 0.8);
$(".teamImage").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo(800, 0.8);
});
$(".teamImage").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo(320, 1);
});
```

})

Comment: Could you accomplish the same thing with a CSS :hover style?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to remove the duration so the opacity changes instantly.
http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/
Just make 0 the 'duration' argument ( the first one )

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".teamImage")
    .fadeTo(0, 0.8)
    .mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(0, 0.8);
    })
    .mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
    });
})
```